# VBA - Error 1004 - CopyPicture of method class failed

Tags: vba, excel

i need some help with my code. I wrote a macro which copies many tables as pictures from different Excel files to PowerPoint, but sometimes it works perfectly, and sometimes appears Error 1004 - CopyPicture of method class failed. Here is my code:

```
Sheets("List1").Select
' group chart
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
' select cells to be copied to PowerPoint:
Range("A1:X83").Select
' copy cells:
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
' paste to PowerPoint:

pptSld.Shapes.Paste.Select
```

I found that for someone was helpful inserting `Sheets("List1").` before `Range("A1:X83").Select`, but it didn't help.
I have this problem at work, where I'm using Office 2010. At home I have Office 2016 and code works perfectly.

Do you have any ideas, how to make it work without any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the habit of using `.Select` for everything; that's what macro-recorder code does, but only because macro-recorder code mimicks every manual action - when automating Office, you don't actually need to reproduce every mouse click you'd do when doing the task manually - instead you work with the Office application's *object model*.

`</rant>`

So you work off `Worksheets("List1")`, and copy a specitic `Range` as a picture:

```
Application.Worksheets("List1").Range("A1:X83").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
```

This code is much more robust than anything that relies on `Selection`: you're calling `.CopyPicture` off a specific `Range` object.

So all that's left to do is to paste:

```
pptSld.Shapes.Paste
```

Note that [`Paste` is a method that doesn't return anything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745532.aspx), so you can't legally do `.Select` on it - but why would you want to `.Select` it anyway?!

If you need to access the newly-created `Shape` object, you can retrieve it from the `pptSld.Shapes` collection:

```
Dim excelScreenshot As Shape
Set excelScreenshot = pptSld.Shapes(pptSld.Shapes.Count)
```

And then whatever you wanted to so with `Selection`, you can now do with `excelScreenshot` - and as a bonus you get *IntelliSense* and auto-completion for working with a strongly-typed object reference, as opposed to `Object`, which makes every member call a late-bound call - in other words you'll get better performance, however unnoticeable it might be.

Comment: thank you a lot for such a full answer. This code works for me, but now I cannot align my Shape on slide. I'm using this code `Dim excelScreenshot As Shape
Set excelScreenshot = pptSld.Shapes(pptSld.Shapes.Count)   excelScreenshot.Left = 25
    excelScreenshot.Top = 100` and i'm getting "Error 13 - Type mismatch"

Comment: @Pelmeshka not sure which instruction is causing that error. Determine which instruction causes the problem, use the debugger (breakpoints/F9, step-through/F8, the locals toolwindow, etc), the object browser/F2 and Google & Stack Overflow to identify the actual types you need to work with... *Failing that*, reproduce the problem with as little code as possible (see [mcve]), and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your references to make sure that you're calling the correct library.

Tools > References

Not sure which on you need, but make sure you have Microsoft Powerpoint xx.x blah blah blah checked.

Comment: better placed as a comment, IMO, since its more of a tip rather than a solid answer.